# Cordova Build failed with error Error code 65 for command xcodebuild with args

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, cordova

I am building a basic JavaScript app in Visual Studio on Windows using Cordova and connecting to a local macbook for compiling.  I get this generic error:
"Build failed with error Error code 65 for command xcodebuild with args"

I have tried everything I could think of to fix the problem, but without knowing what the real error is, I can't figure out what to do.  I completely rebuild my ios certificates, but that didn't work.  I think there might be more details in the build info, so I am including that below.  I didn't see anything in there, but someone with more experience might know:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: JamCruise, Configuration: Release iOS ------
1>    Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript
1>    Task Parameter:Configurations= --noEmitOnError
1>    Task Parameter:YieldDuringToolExecution=True
1>    Task Parameter:ProjectDir=D:\JamCruise\JamCruise\
1>    Task Parameter:ToolsVersion=2.3
1>    Task Parameter:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=False
1>    Task Parameter:PreferredUILang=en-US
1>    Task Parameter:OutputLogFile=bld\iOS\Release\TypeScriptCompilerOutput.txt
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.3\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError --listEmittedFiles --locale en-US
1>  Done executing task "VsTsc".
1>Done building target "CompileTypeScript" in project "JamCruise.jsproj".
1>Target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in file "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets":
1>  Using "MdaVerifySetup" task from assembly "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>  Task "MdaVerifySetup"
1>    Task Parameter:Platform=iOS
1>    Task Parameter:InstanceId=07e374e2
1>  Done executing task "MdaVerifySetup".
1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "JamCruise.jsproj".
1>Target "BuildMDA" in file "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets":
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(Platform)' == 'android' AND '$(TelemetryEnabled)' == 'True' ) was evaluated as ( 'iOS' == 'android' AND 'True' == 'True' ).
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' AND '$(TelemetryEnabled)' == 'True') was evaluated as ( '' != '' AND 'True' == 'True').
1>  Task "VsTac" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>  Using "VsTac" task from assembly "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>  Task "VsTac"
1>    Task Parameter:Platform=iOS
1>    Task Parameter:Configuration=Release
1>    Task Parameter:ProjectName=JamCruise
1>    Task Parameter:BuildServerUrl=http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova
1>    Task Parameter:DebugTarget=iOSLocalDevice
1>    Task Parameter:DetectNpmProxy=True
1>    Task Parameter:InstanceId=07e374e2
    ------ Submitting new build request to: http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=7.1.0&cfg=release&options=--device
    ------ New Build information: {"command":"build","vcordova":"7.1.0","cfg":"release","options":"--device","status":"Uploaded","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"release","buildDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619","buildNumber":619,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2019-01-04T05:42:04.131Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageArgs":null,"message":"Uploaded build request payload.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/upload_619.tgz","appDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2019-01-04T05:42:07.027Z"}
    ------ 01/03/2019 22:42:07 Checking on build status from http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova/build/tasks/619 [Attempt 1]
    ------ New Build information: {"command":"build","vcordova":"7.1.0","cfg":"release","options":"--device","status":"Uploaded","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"release","buildDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619","buildNumber":619,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2019-01-04T05:42:04.131Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageArgs":null,"message":"Uploaded build request payload.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/upload_619.tgz","appDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2019-01-04T05:42:07.027Z"}
    Uploaded - Uploaded build request payload.
    Building - Updating platform.
    ------ 01/03/2019 22:44:28 Checking on build status from http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova/build/tasks/619 [Attempt 29]
    ------ New Build information: {"command":"build","vcordova":"7.1.0","cfg":"release","options":"--device","status":"Error","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"release","buildDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619","buildNumber":619,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2019-01-04T05:42:04.131Z","changeList":{"deletedFiles":[]},"buildSuccessful":false,"messageId":"BuildFailedWithError","messageArgs":["Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device"],"message":"Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device","tgzFilePath":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/upload_619.tgz","appDir":"/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2019-01-04T05:44:26.452Z","appName":"Jam Cruise"}
    Error - Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
    ------ Remote build log follows
1>    MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Remote build error from the build server http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
    [1m[33mUse of cordova.raw.* methods is deprecated and cordova.raw will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to using the top-level cordova.* methods instead.[39m[22m
    [1m[33m[39m[22mNo scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
    Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist"
    Copying plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist" => "/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist"
    No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
    [1m[33mUse of cordova.raw.* methods is deprecated and cordova.raw will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to using the top-level cordova.* methods instead.[39m[22m
    [1m[33m[39m[22mNo scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
    No version specified for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support, retrieving version from config.xml
    No version for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support saved in config.xml or package.json
    Attempting to use npm info for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support to choose a compatible release
    npm info for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support did not contain any engine info. Fetching latest release
    Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support"
    Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" via npm
    Copying plugin "/Users/kevinrevie/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/0.2.3/package" => "/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support"
    No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
    cordova platform add ios
    [1m[33mUse of cordova.raw.* methods is deprecated and cordova.raw will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to using the top-level cordova.* methods instead.[39m[22m
    [1m[33m[39m[22mExecuting script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_platform_add": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-execute-bit-fix.js
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_platform_add": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-remove-plugin-json.js
    No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
    Grabbing pinned version.
    Removing "cordova-" prefix from cordova-ios
    Adding ios project...
    PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
    Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
        Path: platforms/ios
        Package: com.cordova.JamCruise
        Name: Jam Cruise
    Copying iOS template project to /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios
    iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.5
    Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
    No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
    PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
    Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/config.xml
    Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
    Found "merges/ios" folder. Copying its contents into the iOS project.
    Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www, merges/ios] to platforms/ios/www
      mkdir platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src
      copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/exec.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js (new file)
      copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/platform.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/platform.js (new file)
    Current launch storyboard undefined
    Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
    Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.cordova.JamCruise" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Jam Cruise-Info.plist
    Need to update build settings because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    Set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to "1".
    Set ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME to LaunchImage because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    iOS Product Name has not changed (still "Jam Cruise")
    Updating icons at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
    Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
    Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
    This app does not have additional resource files defined
    Prepared iOS project successfully
    Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" following successful platform add of ios
    Found variables for "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support". Processing as cli_variables.
    Installing "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" for ios
    Running command: /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
    Command finished with error code 0: /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
    Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios platform only.
    No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
    Install start for "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" on ios.
    Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
    Action stack processing complete.
    Install complete for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios.
    Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios platform only.
    No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
    Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" following successful platform add of ios
    Found variables for "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Processing as cli_variables.
    Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
    Running command: /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
    Command finished with error code 0: /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
    Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
    No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
    Install start for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on ios.
    Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
    Action stack processing complete.
    Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios.
    Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
    No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-execute-bit-fix.js
    Resolving module name for q => q
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-res-native.js
    Processing res/native for ios
    Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
    Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
    Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
    Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
    Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
    No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
    Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/config.xml
    Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
    Found "merges/ios" folder. Copying its contents into the iOS project.
    Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www, merges/ios] to platforms/ios/www
      copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova_plugins.js platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js (updated file)
    Current launch storyboard undefined
    Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
    Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.cordova.JamCruise" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Jam Cruise-Info.plist
    Need to update build settings because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    Set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to "1".
    Set ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME to LaunchImage because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    iOS Product Name has not changed (still "Jam Cruise")
    Updating icons at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
    Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
    Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
    Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
    This app does not have additional resource files defined
    Prepared iOS project successfully
    No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
    Saving ios@4.5.5 into platforms.json
    No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
    cordova build ios
    [1m[33mUse of cordova.raw.* methods is deprecated and cordova.raw will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to using the top-level cordova.* methods instead.[39m[22m
    [1m[33m[39m[22mNo scripts found for hook "before_build".
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-execute-bit-fix.js
    Resolving module name for q => q
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-res-native.js
    Processing res/native for ios
    Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
    Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
    Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
    Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
    Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
    No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
    Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/config.xml
    Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
    Found "merges/ios" folder. Copying its contents into the iOS project.
    Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www, merges/ios] to platforms/ios/www
    Current launch storyboard undefined
    Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
    Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.cordova.JamCruise" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Jam Cruise-Info.plist
    Need to update build settings because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    Set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to "1".
    Set ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME to LaunchImage because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.
    iOS Product Name has not changed (still "Jam Cruise")
    Updating icons at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
    Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
    Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/Jam Cruise/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
    Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
    This app does not have additional resource files defined
    Prepared iOS project successfully
    No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
    Executing script found in config.xml for hook "before_compile": hooks/xcode8.js
    Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_compile": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-symlink-fix.js
    Resolving module name for q => q
    Resolving module name for glob => glob
    Reading build config file:
    Building project: /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise.xcworkspace
        Configuration: Release
        Platform: device
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise.xcarchive

    Build settings from command line:
        CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
        SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

    Build settings from configuration file '/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig':
        CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
        CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution
        DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = VYQK3ZA9RB
        ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
        HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
        OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
        PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 19621cc2-1e6b-46da-9134-98c035784124
        SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

    error: archive not found at path '/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Jam Cruise.xcarchive'
    ** EXPORT FAILED **

    Failed to build app for buildNumber 619: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
1>  Done executing task "VsTac" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "JamCruise.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "JamCruise.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Remote build error from the build server http://192.168.0.23:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Jam Cruise.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/kevinrevie/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/619/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:03:07.90
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I just need to know what the real error is.  Is there a way to show real errors?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was wrong.  XCode 10 has a new build system that doesn't work with Cordova.  Here is a link to the announcement and the details for the fix to implement:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

For me, I just needed to add this code to my build.json:

```
"buildFlag": [
    "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
]
```

That code tells XCode 10 not to use the new build system.