# ionic ios build fail background geolocation

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I make an ionic app. I build succesfuly to android on windows, but when I want to build it in mac, failed.
[image]

I think somting wrong with the Geolocation, but i don't know what.

```
ionic version: 6.6.0

cordova.cmd plugin ls
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 4.0.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-background-geolocation 3.1.0 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 6.3.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 4.3.0 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging 4.4.0 "FirebaseMessagingPlugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.1 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 3.0.1 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.2 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.4.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's geolocation?  Are there other errors on the screen or in the logs?

Comment: updated the full log i think

Comment: Is there any mention of a build log text file with the actual problem in it?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034365/cordova-build-failed-with-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args

Comment: And you need to do this as well (to fix the team id issue): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson

Answer (score -1):

```
ionic cordova plugin rm background-geolocation
ionic cordova plugin add background-geolocation
```

solve my problem.
I don't know why, but it's work. :D